# Can't run Powershell 64 on Core i7

Tags: powershell, windows-7-x64, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to get into Powershell Workflows, however I get the following error if I attempt to use the "workflow" keyword:

Windows PowerShell Workflow is not supported in a Windows PowerShell x86-based console. Open a Windows PowerShell x64-based console, and then try again.

Common sense would tell you to open the 64bit version:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

It doesn't seem to matter which version of powershell I open, I get the same message.

```
$env:Processor_Architecture always returns x86
```

I've tried this on both my laptops (1st Win7, 2nd Win8) and they both behave the same

```
$env:PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER : 
1st PC: Intel64 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 2, GenuineIntel 
2nd PC: Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
```

Am I just missing something simple?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version in SysWOW64 is the 32-bit version. WOW64 is the 32-bit emulator on 64-bit Windows (WoW means "Windows on Windows"). You need to run the version from system32, which is the 64-bit version.

Comment: which is totally contraintuitive but sadly true

Comment: I feel so dumb. You know, I never really looked into that before. I guess I was assuming that system32 = 32 bit, SysWOW64 = 64 bit.  Thank you for explaining that.